# Android:way Assign "0" to empty array item condition

Tags: java, android, arrays, for-loop

I have a String array and its contents depend on results from a RSS feed. Now, most of the time the array will contain four items. However, on a rare occasion, it will contain three.

I tried the following code in order to search the array for a null value(empty) and then assign 0 to this

```
String[] parts = newmenuItemsString.split(",");
               String s1part1 = parts[0];
               String s1part2 = parts[1];
               String s1part3 = parts[2];
               String s1part4 = parts[3];

for (int i=0; i<=parts.length; i++) 
                   { 
                       if (parts[i]!=null ) {   
                       } else {
                           i = 0;
                       }
                    }
```

Here is my string array and here is the for loop for it.

Basically, I want to check if all items in the array are filled and if one is empty, I want to assign "0" to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be:

```
String[] parts = newmenuItemsString.split(",");
String[] myFourStrings = new String[4];

System.arraycopy(parts, 0, myFourStrings, 0, parts.length);

if (parts.length == 3) {
    myFourStrings[3] = "0";
}
```

This uses two arrays. The first is of unknown length - set by the number of "," in the input string. The second is fixed at 4.

Then we copy all the values of `parts` into the new array. If there are only 3 items, add a 4th.

Note: You should really check whether the `parts` array has more than 4 items, as this would cause an error.

Edit: The full example, with String assignments, and some optimisations:

```
String[] parts = newmenuItemsString.split(",");
String[] myFourStrings;

if (parts.length != 4)
{

    myFourStrings = new String[4];

    System.arraycopy(parts, 0, myFourStrings, 0, parts.length);

    if (parts.length == 3)
    {
        myFourStrings[3] = "0";
    }

}
else
{
    myFourStrings = parts;
}

String s1part1 = myFourStrings[0];
String s1part2 = myFourStrings[1];
String s1part3 = myFourStrings[2];
String s1part4 = myFourStrings[3];
```

In fact, a more general example, taking a variable number of commas, up to a maximum of `maxItems`:

```
int maxItems = 6;
String[] parts = newmenuItemsString.split(",");
String[] myStrings = new String[maxItems];

if (parts.length < myStrings.length) {
    System.arraycopy(parts, 0, myStrings, 0, parts.length);
} else {
    System.arraycopy(parts, 0, myStrings, 0, myStrings.length);
}

for (int i = 0; i < myStrings.length; i++)
{
    if (myStrings[i] == null)
    {
        myStrings[i] = "0";
    }
}

String s1part1 = myStrings[0];
String s1part2 = myStrings[1];
String s1part3 = myStrings[2];
String s1part4 = myStrings[3];
```

Comment: in my code i have added strings to the array so when its split each part is assigned a variable... how would your code then be added to my own? sorry im a little confused

Comment: do i still use the (String s1part1 = parts[0];) part

Comment: @ChronosChris Edited to show a more complete example.

Comment: This is fantastic thank you very much. The code example is very helpful